# ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location. Using aubio in Python

Tags: python, importerror, waf

For a schoolproject I need to make use of the [aubio](http://aubio.org/) library. However, I have a problem compiling it for Windows.

I downloaded the latest source from his git (0.4.0 alpha). Then I compiled it using Cygwin, using the --with-target-platform=win32 to cross-compile it for Windows. It uses waf by the way.
This works without any errors.

Next step is copying the compiled file (libaubio.dll.a) to MinGW library folder. Then I want to compile the Python wrapper for the module, but it shows up the ld.exe cannot find -laubio error. Renaming the libaubio.dll.a to libaubio.a resolves this and compiling succeeds succesfully.

Installing it into the Python folder works perfectly too. But here starts the problem. When trying to import aubio, I get this error: ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.

I have no clue on how to solve this problem. Can anybody help? Or explain the error to me?
Thanks in advance!

Xander

PS. It compiles perfectly on both OSX and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the right solution for you, just a hint. `ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.` I encountered the same error when trying to make my own extension of Python programmed in C. Platform: Windows 32bits.

It was a real pain because this error appeared randomly in interactive as well as in non-interactive mode in all Python environments (Spyder, Notebook, plain console...). I compiled my code using MinGW and Python's distutils (command `python setup.py install`). The compilation gave no warnings or errors and produced pyd file to the correct directory. But when trying to import this module `import example` pro my Python code it irregularly crashed (usually only one out of five attempts to import the module succeeded).

Strange was that on another computer it worked just fine... Well, finally I found workaround - I downloaded a newer version of MinGW (before I had used the version that comes packed in Qt SDK distribution) and compiled the module again. Then it worked with no more crashes. However I did not find any systematic solution or explanation. So I might have something to do with the compiler (maybe absence of its DLLs? I do not know exactly) that was used to generate the pyd file.